# Aggregate rows in MySQL ignoring NULL values into a single row

Tags: mysql

Given a table

```
id  date        job    color  qty
1   2018-12-10  12345  green  1
2   2018-12-11  12345        
3   2018-12-15  12345       
4   2018-12-21  12345  red    
5   2018-12-21  12345         4
6   2018-12-22  12345
```

The `id` column is auto incrementing and is the tables primary key.

A simple query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `job` = '12345' ORDER BY `id` ASC;
```

Would return all records for the job `12345` in the order they were inserted.

Question:
How would I query the table to only return a single row with the most recent values from each column?

The desired row would look like this

```
6   2018-12-22  12345  red    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using `Group_Concat()` with `Substring_Index()` to extract the latest non-null value. `GROUP_CONCAT()` would ignore the `null` values.

```
SELECT 
  MAX(id) AS id, 
  MAX(date) AS date, 
  MAX(job) AS job, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(color ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) AS color, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(qty ORDER BY id DESC), ',', 1) AS qty 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `job` = '12345';
```

One assumption in the above query is that the maximum value of `date` corresponds to maximum `id` value.

Also, since we are only concerned with the "latest" value (fetching only one value); we will not be limited by the `group_concat_max_len` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a separate subquery to find the max value in each separate column:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM yourTable) AS id,
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM yourTable) AS date,
    (SELECT MAX(job) FROM yourTable) AS job,
    (SELECT MAX(color) FROM yourTable) AS color,
    (SELECT MAX(qty) FROM yourTable) AS qty;
```

[image]

### Demo

I have no idea why you want to do this, and it might indicate bad database design/planning on your part.

Comment: Question is not highest-n-per-group problem :-) Do look at the sample data and expected output again.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I was expecting you to appear, and so was covering my bases.  Get ready for the OP to change the question :-)

Comment: OP wants to pick the highest value for each column and combine them in a "fake" row

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT in your query as

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `job` = '12345' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subqueries to get desired result:

```
select max(id) id, 
       job, 
       max(`date`) `date`,
      (select qty from tbl
      where qty is not null
       and tbl.job = job
      order by `date` desc
      limit 1) qty,
      (select color from tbl
      where color is not null
        and tbl.job = job
      order by `date` desc
      limit 1) color
from tbl
group by job
```